# How to record my Mackie digitally via USB?

Tags: cubase, usb

If I want to record my [Mackie ProFX8](http://www.mackie.com/products/profx8/) mixer digitally via USB with my computer, how should I do it? I didn't think that the option appeared in Cubase. Background is that I'm trying to make sound files and the end file gets a background noise due to analog recording:

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/mp3-encoding-and-settings

> No worries, integrated USB I/O takes the pain out of recording. Just
>   connect the ProFX8 to a laptop, start up your included copy of
>   Tracktion 3 Music Production Software (or almost any DAW software out
>   there) and you can record the whole mix.
>
> No Driver Required for Supported Windows (PC) or OS X (Mac) Versions

So I'm supposed to use the [Tracktion](http://www.7bd.com/pdfs/T3_QS.pdf) program but it is not at all clear how to record in Tracktion.

[image]

[image]

In Cubase I've gotten this far and it says nothing about a Mackie or any USB input:

[image]

Maybe this setting below is correct but it doesn't say whether USB is the digital from the Mackie or the USB from the plexgear soundcard.

[image]

And here is another setting I have that says nothing about Mackie and nothing about digital USB.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your Mackie have a USB output?

Comment: what is your Mackie model?

Comment: @Sergio ProFX8.It has USB output which I've physically connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ProFX8 will let you record only a stereo channel (or 2 mono) at a time. I am not familiar with Traction, but in Cubase you can go to menu Devices > Device Setup and choose the Mackie from the first option field (Asio driver).

Then you might need to go to Devices > VST Conections to route the channels to the right input.

[image] 
Here you can choose in Device Port which channel from the Mackie goes to each channel of your audio card. Notice we are in the Input Tab.

After that you can create your tracks and you can choose were the sound comes from to each track. Open the Mixer (F3 or in the menus) and you see this:

[image]

In my example tracks 1,2,3 are Stereo so you just see "Stereo In" in the input field on top of each track. But track 4 & 5 are mono and there you can choose if the audio should come from Left of the Stereo channel you get from the Mackie or Right.

The its just to hit the red button on each track you want to recoed and press REC.

As I said I don't know Tracktion, but there might be similarities in how to route the sound.

EDIT: 
TO export from Cubase you have to first choose the area to Export. You can do this by choosing with the mouse (check the blue bar over the track in image below) or by choosing the track and pressing P (locators to selection).

[image]

Then what is left is to go to menu FILE > EXPORT > AUDIO MIXDOWN

Was this kind of description what you were looking after?

Comment: I don't think anything in Cubase registers the Mackie and I don't understand how this procedure will record the output from my Mackie mixer to an audio file. I think Cubase sucks and will get a hardware sequencer to not use the damn computer at all since it's the computer that creates the noise when it's recording analog from the Mackie.

Comment: If you think that Cubase "sucks" I think it's time to change your opinion. Otherwise take ProTools or Logic. Anyway, Mackie sends thru USB the mix you have in it, that's 2 channels (Left/Right), how to "capture/use" them in Cubase is what I tried to help with. If you want to buy hardware to record without computer do that, but I think a computer solution is better.

Comment: I see nothing about a Mackie in my Cubase 5, Nothing. I tried to achieve this for weeks and I still have no idea. It's not a good user experience. I want to do something simple, generate the final audio file. That should not be the most difficult step. It should not be more difficult than actually creating the tune.

Comment: @909Niklas, just updated my answer (see "Edit"). Just not clear if you succeed to record in Cubase or if you got stopped in choosing the audio device(?). I agree it does not sound like a good user experience.

Comment: It's not working. I updated my original question with the desinformation that Cubase displayes. Nothing about any Mackie and nothing about any digital USB and nothing about how to handle tracks or why even complicate with tracks when I just want a file with what I can play. Thank you Cubase for making the easy part impossible.

Comment: @909Niklas, On your third image, showing VST Connections you are in the OUTPUT tab, on the top/left corner choose "input" and assign the input channels there. If unsure post that image here also.

Comment: Ok, I posted that screenshot. Thank you very much for the help. All the settings is confusing since Cubase have so many settings. I use external instruments like hardware synths and hardware drum machines connected and controlled via MIDI so I don't understand why I must configure VST and route tracks, all I want is an audio file with what I can play.

Comment: @909Niklas, in your screenshot you have 2 inputs assigned, good. Now you can create a new track (audio) mono or stereo as you want and record. Check in the mixer (F3) if you have signal coming in in the volume bars (should show green activity).

Comment: I do believe it's working good! Just that level is a little low. https://soundcloud.com/niklasr/mixdown

Comment: Great @909Niklas! You probably can raise the volume in the Mackie and check in Cubase mixer inputs that you don't go to the red lines. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Does your Mackie have a USB output? If it does then you may need to load drivers onto your PC so that it recognizes the mackie mixer. These drivers probably came with your mixer when you acquired it.

If it doesn't have a USB output then you'll need a USB analogue to digital converter maybe like [this](http://www.soundsliveshop.com/p/Numark_STEREO_iO_DJ_USB_Audio_Interface/NUMARK-STEREOIO?CAWELAID=1830894445&catargetid=1820249875&cadevice=c&cagpspn=pla&gclid=CMbslPyZ87gCFUbHtAodqjQAtg): -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to record each channel, you could get another interface with line in jacks, and use the effects sends from the Mackie.  Push the TS cable in until the first click, and that should send out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (I'm just an amateur figuring things out as I go) the ProFX USB records either from the Main or the Sub 1-4 via the button above Sub 2. You need to install the USB drivers for it but I have no idea where to get them. My computer just automatically installed the driver (windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Mackie web site it says 2x2 for USB I/O.  I would take this to mean 2 channels in and 2 out. With ASIO4All if it could see other channels it would definitely present all channels in to the DAW if they existed.